# SimpleXML and foreach error

Tags: php, api, foreach, simplexml

```
$typeID = 34;
        $reader = simplexml_load_file("http://api.eve-central.com/api/quicklook?typeid=".$typeID);
    foreach ($reader -> buy_orders -> order as $orderrow) {
        if($orderrow->price > $bestPrice)
        {
            if($orderrow->security >= "0.5")
            {
                $bestPrice = $orderrow->price;
                $bestStation = $orderrow->station_name;
                $bestStationID = $orderrow->station;
            }
        }
    }
```

is giving me:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

and I don't understand why. The idea here is to run through each buy order listed there, and compare the prices, if the order is higher, set that as best. Do so until all orders are done and the variables will list best prices, best station and the stationID to be used later. I've looked a number of StackOverflow questions, references, etc. Many examples report going three deep is fine, so I don't get WHY it's an invalid argument.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please add the schema of your xml or sample xml?

I'm new to PHP, but according to the PHP foreach sample,
I guess it's the line of 'foreach' caused this warning, and maybe it should work like:

```
foreach ($reader -> buy_orders as $orderrow) {
...
}
```

if the $reader -> buy_orders is the array expression you should not add '->order'

Please refer to
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement

I didn't test my answer, you may try if that works for you and let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After closer examination of the XML document, I found I skipped a level. It should have been

```
foreach($reader -> quickorder -> buy_orders -> order as $buyOrder)
```